# Como realizar un GET por ID y por Nombre en AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, nodejs

Soy bastante nuevo trabajando con angular y node js. Mi problema es que tengo un GET para buscar por ID(funciona correctamente), pero quisiera que dependiendo de un radio bottom también me buscara por nombre. Entonces solo consigo que me busque por uno de los dos.

Adjunto codigo:

**Index.js**

```
app.get(baseAPI + "/contacts/:name", (request, response) => {
console.log("GET /contacts/"+name);
var name = request.params.name;
contacts.get(name,(err,contacts)=>{
    if (contacts.length === 0) {
        response.sendStatus(404);
    }
    else {
        response.send(contacts);  
    }
   });
   });

app.get(baseAPI + "/contacts/:ID", (request, response) => {
console.log("GET /contacts/"+ID);
var ID = request.params.ID;
contacts.get(ID,(err,contacts)=>{
    if (contacts.length === 0) {
        response.sendStatus(404);
    }
    else {
        response.send(contacts);  
    }
});
});
```

**another.js**

```
$scope.getcon = function (radio, yolo){       

  if (radio === yolo) {
       $http.get("/api/v1/contacts/"+radio).then(function(response) {
 $scope.contacts= response.data;
 console.log("seleccionado");
    });
 } else {

  $http.get("/api/v1/contacts/"+yolo).then(function(response) {
    $scope.contacts= response.data;
  });
  console.log("no esta seleccionado");  
  console.log(radio);
  console.log(yolo);
}
```

**Contacts.js**

```
Contacts.prototype.get = function(name, callback) {
  return db.find({name:name}, callback);
};

Contacts.prototype.get = function(ID, callback) {
  return db.find({ID:ID}, callback);
};
```

**HTML**

```
<!Doctype html>
<html ng-app="ContactListApp">
<head>
    <title>
        Contact List
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/vendors/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/vendors/grid.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="contact-list-app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="list-ctrl.js"></script>



</head>


<body ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <title>Untitled</title> 


     <header>
    <div class="row test">
        <div class= "col-lg-6">
          <!--  <a href="#"><img  class="logo" src="https://www.informatica.us.es/docs/imagen-etsii/logo-ETSII-US-Vertical-Negro.png"></img></a> -->
           <a href="#"><img  class="logo" src="http://www.libreriaserviciomedico.com/files/14919"></img></a> 
         </div>

         <div class= "col-lg-6">
             <nav style="float:right">
                 <a  href="login">Sign Out</a> |  
                 <a  href="login">Help</a> 
             </nav>


         </div>
    </div>


</header>
<Section class="form1">

    <h2>Research Groups</h2> 
    <br>
    <form name="Research Groups" class="formulario">

    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id=tabla>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <td><label for="search">Search by:</label></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="1"  id="radio1"  checked>Group ID<br>
                <input type="radio" name="luis" value="2"  id="radio2" >Group Name<br></td>


            <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="newContact.name"> </td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary"   ng-click="getcon(newContact.name, newContact.ID)" id="boton" >Get One </button> 

        </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Responsable</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>


        <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:newContact.ID">
            <td> {{contact.ID}}</td>
            <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
            <td>{{contact.phone}}</td>
            <td>{{contact.email}}<button class="boton" ng-click="console.log($index)">View Details</button></td>

        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>

    </Section>


</body>
```

Comment: Bienvenido para entender mejor la pregunta deberias de poner el html

Comment: Hola, lo que estás haciendo en Contact.js no es definir 2 métodos get con distintos parámetros, sino sobrescribir la primera definición con la segunda. Es decir, al final de todo, sólo tendrás una definición de "get" que será get(ID, callback).

Comment: Saludos S. Bonet, ese es mi problema, como podria definir la otra funcion get para el nombre, ya que si utilizo otro nombre no funciona